# Select two Pivot Tables (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need to select two Pivot Tables on the same Excel sheet at the same time. The code to select one Pivot table is:

```
    Dim PT1 As PivotTable               
    Set PT1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)    
    PT1.TableRange1.Select
```

How to select two Pivot tables? The code below selecting only one table (which is on the last code row):

```
    Dim PT1 As PivotTable  
    Dim PT2 As PivotTable  
    Set PT1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)  
    Set PT2 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2)    
    PT1.TableRange1.Select  
    PT2.TableRange2.Select
```

Thanks

Comment: Try - `Application.Union(PT1.TableRange1, PT2.TableRange1).Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Tim. That works perfectly:

```
    Dim PT1 As PivotTable  
    Dim PT2 As PivotTable  
    Set PT1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)  
    Set PT2 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2) 
    Application.Union(PT1.TableRange1, PT2.TableRange1).Select
```